# Cannot declare interface , because the name is already in use

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, setup-di-compile

After creating a simple interface in my new module. I typed in bin/magento setup:di:compile, and I get an error saying that the name is already in use.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Company\Test\Api;

/*
 *  @api
 */
interface XyzInterface {
    public function getSomething();
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 2 secs 52.0 MiBPHP 
Fatal error:  Cannot declare interface Company\Test\Api\XyzInterface, because the name is already in use in .../app/code/Company/Test/Api/XyzInterface.php on line 13
```

The line is the "interface XyzInterface"
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please run the command with -vvv option to see stack trace? Might be the file is included twice by some reason.

Comment: It just shows "PHP Fatal Error"

Comment: You can also try to enable xdebug. I think it should help displaying the backtrace.

Comment: i got this error also because of mistyped "namespace" class

Answer (score 36):

Today I received the same-type error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Class\Name\Here , because the name is already in use in /var/www/m2/magento2/app/code/path/to/the/class.php on line 100

where the line 100 is end of the file.

Approximately after 4 hours of debugging I really find the reason: a misprint in the namespace declaration. Till the final moment I didn't believe that it is a typographical error in names declaration, but when I have rewritten all names anew - the mistake has disappeared. [This article](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/128692434875/magento-2-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class) was very helpful:

> I’ll scratch my head for a while, wonder what’s going on, and
>   eventually realize it’s this
>
> ```
> Pulsetorm
> ```
>
> i.e. I’ve mistyped a namespace name, and when the initial autoloads
>   loads the class file, it won’t have defined the class it’s looking
>   for, and then a second autoloader (Composer’s usually) loads it again,
>   and tries to redefine the same incorrect class.
>
> i.e., Magento wanted the class
>
> ```
> Pulsestorm\Helloworld\Observers\Block
> ```
>
> but I defined
>
> ```
> Pulsetorm\Helloworld\Observers\Block
> ```
>
> thanks to the wrong namespace.

Thank you, Alan Storm :)

**UPDATE:**

Another type of that error is incorrect Namespace declaration with missing part of the namespace, as in this example:

**Error:**

> Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 
>   14% 1 sec 50.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class
>   Migration\Step\Version11410to2000Test, because the name is already in
>   use in
>   /var/www/vhosts/rwld/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/tests/unit/testsuite/Migration/Step/UrlRewrite/Version11410to2000Test.php
>   on line 109

where the line 109 is end of the file.

In the file `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/tests/unit/testsuite/Migration/Step/UrlRewrite/Version11410to2000Test.php` we found the namespace as `Migration\Step` when the correct namespace should be `Migration\Step\UrlRewrite` because path to this class is `Migration/Step/UrlRewrite`. After changing of the namespace to `Migration/Step/UrlRewrite` the error is gone.

Comment: I had same issue, this is crazy issue

Comment: Also just want to add to this, take **extra care** when naming your directories as the casing **must** match - this could have also been another two hours wasted!