# setup:di:compile error because of duplicated class of data-migration-tool

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, setup-di-compile

I'm running into following fatal error when trying to execute the setup:di:compile command:

> Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Migration\Step\Version11410to2000Test, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/tests/unit/testsuite/Migration/Step/UrlRewrite/Version11410to2000Test.php on line 109

I tried to re-compile because I was getting an 404 on backend (triggered by magento, not apache websever).

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**
It is a fresh Magento 2 install, except for adding the official (and correct) data-migration-tool.

Comment: Today I received the same-type error. Perhaps this answer will be useful for people who will comes here from Google (as me): http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124654/cannot-declare-interface-because-the-name-is-already-in-use/136911#136911

Comment: "Fatal error: Cannot declare class Less_Version, because the name is already in use" I run "setup:di:compile" get error,what shoould I do?[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzfiF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzfiF.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change and give different class name for your controller class

this might be issue because your controller class name also used by some other controller

example shown in below url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class

And if this is the not case then

please delete `di` folder in var

Comment: I didn't name anything, it is a fresh install except for installing data-migration-tool (which comes from magento) - sorry I didn't mention this.

Comment: please delete `di` folder in var

Answer (score 8):

A more direct answer to this problem is:

At the top of the file: `{magento-base}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/tests/unit/testsuite/Migration/Step/UrlRewrite/Version11410to2000Test.php`

Replace:

```
namespace Migration\Step;
```

With:

```
namespace Migration\Step\UrlRewrite;
```

Comment: That worked but my `vendor` folder is ignored do not a long term fix

Comment: This is the "correct" fix as it is a known bug: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/155