# Calling block from phtml gives an error [Solved]

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, phtml

The error that I'm getting is :

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class ExpectedDelivery, because the name
>   is already in use in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/Fabelio/Checkout/Block/ExpectedDelivery.php on
>   line 89

I called the block in my html like this :

```
<?php
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Fabelio\Checkout\Block\ExpectedDelivery'); 
?>
```

and here is the Block class :

```
class ExpectedDelivery extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $todoItemFactory;
    protected $sessionCustomer;
    protected $sessionCheckout;

    /**
     * ExpectedDelivery constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Session $sessionCustomer,
        SessionCheckout $sessionCheckout,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->sessionCustomer = $sessionCustomer;
        $this->sessionCheckout = $sessionCheckout;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    function _prepareLayout(){
    }

    public function getExpectedDelivery()
    {
        return 'goodbye magento 2'; 


    }
}
```

Any idea how to call the block the right way in magento 2.1.8 ?

Solve : The problem here is because of I forget to add the `namespce Fabelio\Checkout\Block;` in the Block class. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please share code of `app/code/Fabelio/Checkout/Block/ExpectedDelivery.php`

Comment: have you checked this answer for generated error https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136911/20064

Comment: if you calling `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Fabelio\Checkout\Block\ExpectedDelivery'); ` in phtml then it is wrong . And `this->getLayout()` should be ` $block->getLayout()`

Comment: @AmitBera yup I have modify the `$this` to `$block` but still doesn't work

Comment: @AmitBera updated with block class

Comment: can you share full code of ExpectedDelivery.php file

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya it is a fullcode :). looks like calling this block in phtml using above code only works on magento 2.0.

Comment: for your class ExpectedDelivery where defined namespace of full path?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya  yup the error is gone now, but doesn't show display the return value `goodbye magento 2`. Thanks everyonw this is because I forgot the namespace here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call in your phtml file with below code,

```
<?php
   $expectedBlock =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Fabelio\Checkout\Block\ExpectedDelivery'); 
   echo $expectedBlock->getExpectedDelivery();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you this  was cause by silly mistake I forgot to add the namespace :D.