# Fatal error: Cannot declare class Product, because the name is already

Tags: magento2

I have try to create custom module in magento 2 but i have got error like

**Fatal error: Cannot declare class Product, because the name is already in use in /var/www/mymagento/app/code/Plus/Demo/Model/Product.php on line 2**

Here is my **Product.php**

```
<?php
class Product {     
public function sayHello() {
    echo "hi";
  }
}
```

And here is my **test.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$quote = $obj->get('Plus\Demo\Model\Product');   
//I have created say fucntion under Product.php file
echo '<pre>';
print_r($quote->sayHello());
echo '</pre>'; */
```

I tried but i still can not success.

Thanks in advance

[TRY](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124654/cannot-declare-interface-because-the-name-is-already-in-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add namespace in `Product.php`

> app/code/Plus/Demo/Model/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Plus\Demo\Model;

class Product
{    
    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
}
```