# After upgrading Magento2.2.3 to Magento 2.2.5 getting Error

Tags: magento2, class

After upgrading Magento2.2.3 to Magento 2.2.5 below getting Error

> Fatal error: Cannot use Magento\Sales\Model\Order as Order because the name is already in use in D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\temando\module-shipping-m2\Model\OrderInterfaceBuilder.php on line 12

Comment: check this link may be it helps to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136911

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temando_shipping` module is magento module powered by Temando check here [magento devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.2CE.html)

Possible are to resolve your area

1. Disable your module if it is not required.
2. Contact to [temando.com](https://temando.com/en/connectors/magento-2-shipping-software) to report an issue or download new module with your current magento version.

I hope it will help to you.

Comment: Welcome  @RutveeSojitra :)